# FirebaseListObservable and ion-slides not working

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angularfire2, ion-slides

I have a FirebaseListObservable and want to iterate over the resulting elements to create ion-slides:

```
<ion-slides [initialSlide]="currentDay - 1">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let secret of secrets | async let i = index;">
    <big-secret-card [secret]="secret"></big-secret-card>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

However when I do this, `initialSlide` doesn't work. I think this might be a bug of `ion-slides`.

What is the best way to handle this? Skip the nice async pipe and subscribe to the `FirebaseListObservable` instead, and include an `*ngIf="secrets.length>0"` to `ion-slides`?

In this case do I have to use `unsibscribe()` when leaving the page?

Or is there any better solution?

Comment: what is `currentDay` value?

Comment: It is some value from 1-7 where we always have 7 slides (indexed from 0-6 this is why -1). Also when I "hardcode" for example [initialSlide]=3 it alsways jumps opens with slide 0.

Comment: it looks like the async op and view are not in sync..have you tried an if condition?

Comment: @suraj As a workaround I am now converting the FirebaseListObservable into a regular Observable and pre-load with an array of 7 empty objects

Answer (score 1):

I am now using this workaround, converting the FirebaseListObservable into a regular Observable and pre-loading with an array of 7 empty Objects. It works for my case:

```
  getWeek(week): Observable<any> {
    // get all secrets of one week into an array
    let emptyWeek = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}];
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      observer.next(emptyWeek);
      let week$ = this.af.database.list('/dhsweek/en/week)).subscribe(result => observer.next(result));
      return () => {
        // unsubscribe function called automatically by async pipe when leaving page
        week$.unsubscribe();
      }
    })
  }
```